Added directive for wrapping route
I have added a directive
object CustomDirectives extends Directives {

  def wrapWithTracing(name: String)(innerRoute: => Route)(implicit req: RequestContext): Route = {
    //start span

    // Apply the inner route and handle completion
    ctx =>
      Try {
        innerRoute // Execute the inner route
      } match {
        case Success(routeResult) =>
           //End span`
          routeResult
        case Failure(ex) =>
          // End span with error on failure
          throw ex
      }
  }
}

And using this as below:
def get: Route = {
  path("/get") {
    mapResponse(wrapToJson) {
      implicit ctx => {
        CustomDirectives.wrapWithTracing("/get") {
          auth() {
            (param) =>
            complete {
               execute(param)
            }
          }
         }
        }.apply(ctx) // Manually apply the context here
    }
  }
}

I cant change the above code much as it is well tested all i want to do is to wrap it within directive so that i can start before call and end span after call the original endpoint is as below
def get: Route = {
  path("/get") {
    mapResponse(wrapToJson) {
      implicit ctx => {
          auth() {
            (param) =>
            complete {
               execute(param)
            }
          }
        }.apply(ctx) // Manually apply the context here
    }
  }
}

My expectation is that when get is invoked it will first start the span in wrapWithTracing then it will call auth() directive and then execute() and after execute is done it will end the span in wrapWithTracing based on the result of (auth/execute()).
However when this executes it first calls the auth specific code and then wrapWithTracing.
Am I doing anything wrong here?
auth definition:
def authReq()((f:Option[X]) = Route)(implicit req: RequestContext): Route = {...}


Could you provide a minimal reproducible example? Which library are you using?

Maybe Tracing for akka could help you
